# sql server 2008 windows authentication add user from another pc

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-authentication

I want to connect to a database server on another computer (on the same network) using Windows 7. I have SQL Server 2008 r2 running on win 7 as a server, and the clients are PCs running Win 7 or XP.

When I want to add the user to the server computer, the server can't change the location to search the user because there's no other location available beside the server. What do I need to configure to get this done?

P.S. SQL authentication is not an option because I'm using filestream. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use mixed mode authentication (also known as SQL Server Authentication) if you are not connected to a domain. You can find more details on TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

Comment: i cant use mixed mode because I'm using filestream in my table, can i create/join a domain using only win 7?

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Make sure your database Server Authentication is SQL Server and WindowsAuthentication mode and you SQL Server Management Studio.

To set up SQL Server and Widows Authentication Mode.

1. Connect to you SQL Server Instance
2. Right Click the go to properties
3. Choose Security on Select a Page Container
4. Then Choose SQL Server and Widows Authentication Mode on Server Authentication.
5. Click OK

Regards

Comment: sql authentication is not an option

Comment: using mixed mode you can create username and password without having a domain. Something like user_admin as userName and user@admin as password using mixed mode.

Comment: i cant use sql authentication mode because i'm using filestream